# Configuring gitea to work with openldap, user not found error

Tags: configuration, ldap, openldap, gitea

I'm trying to setup gitea with an openldap authentication on a local kind cluster. I was able to get both services started and open the web ui for both. But I am stuck trying to integrate them. I initially encountered err=49 which was caused by an incorrect bind account credential. Now I feel like I have everything correct however it always comes back with the error `user does not exist` regardless of what I try.

I am able to login with the user on the openldap phpadmin.

Adding random charecters to the host or the bind gives a different error, so I assume this is correct.

I've tried different userFilter values using `sAMAccountName=%s` and `cn=*` but I don't know enough about ldap to really know what the value should be. none of the values I tried worked.

logs in openldap:

[image: openldap error]

error in gitea:

[image: login error in gitea]

openldap configuration:

```
  customLdifFiles:
    01-initial.ldif: |-
      dn: ou=groups,dc=archbox
      objectclass: organizationalUnit
      objectclass: top
      ou: groups
      
      dn: cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=archbox
      cn: admins
      gidnumber: 500
      memberuid: tuser
      objectclass: posixGroup
      objectclass: top
      
      dn: cn=users,ou=groups,dc=archbox
      cn: users
      gidnumber: 501
      objectclass: posixGroup
      objectclass: top
      
      dn: ou=users,dc=archbox
      objectclass: organizationalUnit
      objectclass: top
      ou: users
      
      dn: cn=test,ou=users,dc=archbox
      cn: test
      gidnumber: 500
      givenname: test
      homedirectory: /home/users/tuser
      loginshell: /bin/bash
      objectclass: inetOrgPerson
      objectclass: posixAccount
      objectclass: top
      sn: user
      uid: tuser
      uidnumber: 1000
      userpassword: {MD5}WcTy5IxPSAXRNZlv17HWwg==

      dn: cn=gitea gitea,ou=users,dc=archbox
      cn: gitea gitea
      gidnumber: 501
      givenname: gitea
      homedirectory: /home/users/ggitea
      objectclass: inetOrgPerson
      objectclass: posixAccount
      objectclass: top
      sn: gitea
      uid: ggitea
      uidnumber: 1001
      userpassword: {MD5}WcTy5IxPSAXRNZlv17HWwg==
  env:
    LDAP_ORGANISATION: "ArchBox"
    LDAP_DOMAIN: "archbox"
    LDAP_BASE_DN: "dc=archbox"
  adminPassword: adminadmin
  configPassword: configconfig
  replicaCount: 1
  phpldapadmin:
    ingress:
      enabled: true
      path: /
      hosts:
      - ldapadmin.archbox
```

gitea configuration:

```
  gitea:
    ldap:
      enabled: true
      name: "archldap"
      securityProtocol: unencrypted
      host: "openldap-openldap-stack-ha.default"
      port: "389"
      userSearchBase: ou=users,dc=archbox
      userFilter: cn=%s 
      adminFilter: cn=admin,ou=groups,dc=archbox
      emailAttribute: mail
      bindDn: cn=gitea gitea,ou=users,dc=archbox
      bindPassword: giteagitea
      usernameAttribute: cn
```

Answer (score 0):

The log level "debug" revealed, that (in my case) the ldap user filter was busted. I was using `(objectClass=<MyCustomClass>)`. The user filter HAS TO contain the %s that is substituted for the username.
In your case your user filter is missing the outer brackets.

I hope I was able to help you or any one else experiencing this kind of behaviour.

Best, Rincewind